# FFmpeg live streaming RGB frame buffer

Tags: c, ffmpeg, rtmp

When we have a local video file [This code](https://github.com/leixiaohua1020/simplest_ffmpeg_streamer/blob/master/simplest_ffmpeg_streamer/simplest_ffmpeg_streamer.cpp#L137) works for streaming. What we want to achieve is to change input file with RGB frame buffer that we grab from screen. The code below uses input file's `time_base` for PTS and DTS calculation.

```
if(pkt.stream_index==videoindex) {
    AVRational time_base=ifmt_ctx->streams[videoindex]->time_base;
    AVRational time_base_q={1,AV_TIME_BASE};
    int64_t pts_time = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, time_base, time_base_q);
    int64_t now_time = av_gettime() - start_time;
    if (pts_time > now_time)
        av_usleep(pts_time - now_time);
}

in_stream  = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
/* copy packet */
//Convert PTS/DTS
pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035387/encoding-frames-to-video-with-ffmpeg) which increments PTS value by one for every frame `VideoSt.Frame->pts = VideoSt.NextPts++;` saving in local file or streaming to Wowza server works (low quality) but fails on Youtube and Twitch.  `av_interleaved_write_frame` function returns error -22. To improve quality we lowered `qmin` and `qmax` values but the bit-rate of video increased too much (30Mb/s and even more for HD video).

```
VideoSt.Ctx->codec_id = VideoCodec->id;
VideoSt.Ctx->width = ViewportSize.X;
VideoSt.Ctx->height = ViewportSize.Y;
VideoSt.Stream->time_base = VideoSt.Ctx->time_base = { 1, 30 };
VideoSt.Ctx->time_base = timeBase;
VideoSt.Ctx->gop_size = 60;
VideoSt.Ctx->bit_rate = 400000;
VideoSt.Ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
VideoSt.Ctx->qmin = 1;
VideoSt.Ctx->qmax = 2;
VideoSt.Ctx->max_qdiff = 3;
VideoSt.Ctx->qcompress = 1.0f;
```

**How can we stream lossless quality video with reasonable bit-rate using flv1 codec? If streaming to Youtube or Twitch fails is it just a problem with requirements of this services or there's an issue with encoding?**

Regarding error code -22 there's a [detailed explanation](https://thompsonng.blogspot.am/2011/09/ffmpeg-avinterleavedwriteframe-return.html) which explains how we should increment PTS and DTS values.

**In which cases calculating PTS and DTS values are necessary?**

And by the way what are these PTS and DTS? After reading many posts and [Understanding PTS and DTS in video frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595288/understanding-pts-and-dts-in-video-frames#13646293) accepted answer I still do not understand.